# Adding 2D Measurements to 3D coordinates

Tags: geometry, 3d, solid-geometry

Apologies if this is the wrong place, or if the question is stupid, I get flustered easily with math.

I have a set of 3D coordinates, which describe four positions of a object within a room taken by a camera. Imagine I am holign a piece of paper vertically in front of a camera, I have the four corner points of this object. (please see diagram for details).

[Diagram of setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aJfj.png)

The four points describe the four corners of an object in the room, but the object also possesses other features, mainly dips and valleys in it's design. I would like to get the 3D positions of these features, for graphing purposes.

[Example of shape in room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqzyp.png)

Given I have the two 3D points, and all the 2D data of the shape (its height, width etc in centimetres), is there an easy way to use this data to get more 3D points, such as where the dips are?

Edit: These are the four points I have:

(432.8458196, 28.52526426, -119.3253036)

(430.6633017, 29.41752562, -80.5229784)

(404.8092209, 126.9603963, -83.04548288)

(406.0723883, 128.6560902, -119.3584913)

I also have a few other points in the world, such as the positions of a robot arm which was interacting with the object, and as close to paralele with the object as possible:

(460.6903766, 52.57003202, -78.05766964)

(446.4389674, 50.82420874, -81.01552504)

(443.7663845, 49.770538, -81.0743616)

(441.5178063, 49.50744226, -83.29886566)

Additionally, the 2D data I know is in mm, for example, 56mm from the one edge of the object, the height of the object reduces by 6mm, it then alters again after 350mm etc. Given this information, I can easily convert it into 2D coordinates.

Comment: Do you know where the 3D points lie, on the 2D shape?

Comment: I do, so the 3D points are the top left and top right corners of the 2D shape. I am in essence trying to get the points in between those two 3D points via information from the 2D shape.

Comment: And the 2D shape lies on a vertical plane (i.e. parallel to z axis), right?

Comment: I think so, although the Z-axis very slightly fluctuates from one corner to the other (3cmm, give or take) due to the angle it was facing our sensor.

Comment: Hmm, you must know somehow the plane to which the shape belongs. You should know, for instance, the 3D coordinates of a third point, not aligned with the other two.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only points I have available are all 4 points of the plane in the 3D space (all four corners).
Is there no way for me to essentially take these 4 points and impose the data I have from my 2D model into them?

Comment: At least one more point in the plane of the shape would be fine, provided it is not aligned with the others. You should perhaps edit your question and add a sample of data.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance so far, I have updated the question with some coordinates of the points I have, plus extra coordinates of another object in the world. I hope it will be enough data to achieve what I am trying to do.

Comment: For the 2D shape, I have all the measurements in mm (as I have the object physically with me) so I could also provide 2D coordinates of all the points I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you know the 3D coordinates of three points of your 2D shape, labeled $A$, $B$, $C$ in figure below. To find the coordinates of point $P$ you must draw two axes $AC$ and $AB$ (not necessarily perpendicular) and
compute numbers $t$ and $u$ as in figure below:
$$
t={AD\over AB},\quad u={AE\over AC},
$$
where $PD$ is parallel to $AC$ and $PE$ is parallel to $AB$. Note that $AD$ and $AE$ are *signed* distances, that is $AD>0$ if $D$ lies on ray $AB$, otherwise $AD<0$, and the same for $AE$ on ray $AC$.

The 3D coordinates of $P$ are then given by
$$
P=(1-t-u)A+tB+uC.
$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you for writing such a full answer, and the diagram is very useful as well. Could you clarify a few things for me though? When computing t & u, am I correct in assuming that I use my 2D coordinates, and the 3D coordinates are only used at the end when calculating P? Additionally, I am assuming the / in t= AD/AB is the dot product of those two distances?

Comment: Yes, of course you compute $t$ and $u$ on the 2D shape, while to compute $P$ you must use 3D coordinates. But $AD/AB$ is the *ratio* of the distances. E.g. if $AD=12\ $mm and $AB=78\ $mm, then $AD/AB=12/78\approx 0.154$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, the equation works beautifully. Thanks once again, your help is very much appreciated.